# The best way for extending a model

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views

According the Backbone.js documentation [Model-parse](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-parse) does the following:

> parse is called whenever a model's data is returned by the server, in
>   fetch, and save.

To augment models I've already loaded I use `Model.parse()`.  I accomplish this by using `fetch` to make an additional request for data, then use that data to add properties to an existing model.

*Example:*

the fetch object is `{age: 19}`
after the parser will be `{age: 19, isAdult: true}`

When I perform the save request, in the PUT request I also have other parameters not needed (for example isAdult).   I would like to have the original model (without additional parameters in PUT request).

What is the best way to achieve my goal in Backbone?

Comment: @AntoJs - you're question wasn't very clear.  I tried to flush out the idea *i think* you were trying to convey.  Make sure my edit was true to your problem.

Comment: @EBarr you got the point of my question. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly ....

When backbone talks to a server using a save  it sends a *complete respresentation* of the model.  As the docs put it :

> The attributes hash (as in set) should contain the attributes you'd
>   like to change — keys that aren't mentioned won't be altered — **but, a
>   complete representation of the resource will be sent to the server**.

So the default behavior is to send the complete model.  If you want to implement you're own logic you're going to have to override the `sync` method.   Dig through the expanded backbone code a bit and you'll see this comment above `sync` :

> // Override this function to change the manner in which Backbone persists
>    // models to the server. You will be passed the type of request, and the model in question.

I would use the default implementation of sync as my starting point.

Comment: `sync` eventually does a `model.toJSON()` to get the `data` for the `$.ajax` call so you could hack up a `sync` on the model that only uses a slice of the normal `toJSON` value. I still think fixing the server code to whitelist all incoming data makes sense but replacing `sync` would also make sense if `isAdult` was a big pile of extra stuff rather than just a simple boolean flag.

Comment: @muistooshort - I agree with white listing.  Coming from a .net MVC/WebAPI perspective - it's baked into the cake with the model binder.  Although, I also understand the instinct to remove extraneous data from calls, particularly if the calls are high frequency (shorter strings to parse server side) or you can prevent many K of data from traversing the wire (lots of unneeded text? mobile where a few K can make a large difference?).

Comment: For the record, I'm not disagreeing with you. And yes, the bytes do add up pretty quickly in the mobile world. I actually think Backbone should have an `unparse` or `serialize` method that `sync` could use instead of `toJSON`, the default would just `return _.clone(this.attributes)` as `toJSON` does but a distinct method would be nice for this particular use case and offer nice symmetry with the existing `parse`. Maybe I should do a pull request.

Comment: That sounds like a workable solution to me.  I know I would utilize it.